# Change z-index after load

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have a function that gets called when a user scrolls to check for scrollTop() and after a certain scroll happens it changes the menu's z-index from -1 to 1. However this only occurs on a scroll so if the user refreshes the site the menu is virtually unusable until the next scroll occurs.

Is there a way for me to call this and check if the amount of screen scrolled (after the refresh not a user scroll) meets the criteria change the z-index?

My JS:

```
    function getPosition(){
       var y = $(window).scrollTop();
       var status = (y > 880) ? true : false;
       //console.log(status);
       if(status)
           $('#actual-menu').css('z-index', 1);
       else
           $('#actual-menu').css('z-index', -1);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

z-index property has no effect on non-positioned elements, the element must be either  relatively positioned ,absolutely positioned, or fixed.Replace your line with this:

Try adding this  first ,

```
$("#actual-menu").css('position', 'relative');

$('#actual-menu').css('z-index', 1);
```

Comment: I replaced the line, thanks and the element is positioned but still nothing after the user reloads

Answer (score 0):

Just run `getPosition` inside of your `ready` event.

[Functioning Example](http://www.powerlessdynamo.com/stack_exchange/answers/15049437_change-z-index-after-load.html#end)

var limit = 50;

```
$(function () {

    function getPosition() {
             var y = $(window).scrollTop();
             var status = (y > limit) ? true : false;

             if (status) {
                     $('#actual-menu').css('zIndex', 1);
             } else {
                     $('#actual-menu').css('zIndex', -1);
             }
    }

    $(document).on('scroll', getPosition);

    getPosition();
});
```

Comment: I tried that but since there has been no user scroll it marks scrollTop() as 0

Comment: What browser? In Firefox it reports a number on refresh.

Comment: Chrome, might have to do with my css I guess